# File extension not separated by dot

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

```
String filename = uri.getPath();
```

Gives me this string `file:///storage/emulated/0/.temp/file-2092620235jpg`

What is the best way to add a dot before file extension?

Comment: are you sure the end `jpg` is not in the file name? `getPath()` doesn't return the extension so technically the file name is `file-2092620235jpg.jpg`. Check the actual file name using file explorer

Comment: is the file extension is always jpg?

Comment: @th3pat3l: "getPath() doesn't return the extension" -- are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes i´m sure about that

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the file extension is three letters long (so, no docx or similar), you can always try manipulating string in this way:

```
int length = filename.length();
String result = filename.substring(0, length - 3) + "." + filename.substring(length - 3);
```